# Ajuda com Diretorio Template Django

Tags: python, template

Galera, começando a estudar Python com Django agora e surgiu uma duvida aqui que não to conseguindo resolver.

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNoteExist: home.html
```

Views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

urls.py


from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path

from simplemooc.core import views as views_core


urlpatterns = [

    path('', views_core.home, name='home'),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

settings.py

```py
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 't1y1m8wwub+br!*1)d4k#$$we^ceqw78ufc-t)&pn5j4=tny*_'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'simplemooc.core',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'simplemooc.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

'''TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
    'simplemooc/core/template',
 ]'''

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'simplemooc.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Eu estou seguindo um curso, já fiz algumas mudanças pela diferença de versões, porem essa parte eu não estou conseguindo solucionar.

Answer (score 0):

Em sua variável `TEMPLATES` adicione `"template"` no `'DIRS': []`. 
O django buscará automaticamente pela pasta template dentro das aplicações.

Deve ficar assim:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['template'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Ola @Victor, fiz uma edição na sua resposta, veja se ela representa sua intenção, caso não você pode [reverte-la aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/404908/revisions) =D

Comment: Obrigado pela correção @IcaroMartins esqueci de formatar.